# Authentication and login in frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

I have created a react typescript app. I made a login page in the app recently. I wanted to know if there is a way to authenticate and login in to the React app without the backend server. I will be using MongoDB to store the data.

Comment: If you mean authentication on the front end then it is a bad idea and not advisable.